# BootStrap and Firebug/

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I am having an issue where Firebug and chrome dev tools can not inspect a single element of a page when it contains a div with bootstrap classes="navbar navbar-fixed-top". Only the full page or the individual elements of NavBar can be inspected.

I assume this is a common problem but I can not seem to find any documentation about it. Is there a work around for this issue?

Comment: Im able to inspect induvidual elements.. in a site created with bootstrap.. can you give more details..

Comment: If I remove the div and the close tag for       <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"  style="min-height: 900px">     from the master page then can I inspect each element but the page looks ridiculous.

Comment: I can drill down in the html to a specific element but I can not sure the tool tool click on one. It just shows the whole page as one element.